# staging database and etl processes

Tags: ssis, etl, data-warehouse

Problems can occur, if the ETL processeses start hitting the staging database before the staging database is refreshed. What are best practices to prevent this from happening? I currently see these two options:

(1) Never run ETL processeses before staging refresh has finished

(2) Have 2 staging databases which are swapped between refresh cycles.

Comment: Number 1 is the obvious. I like number 2 but I've only heard it used for the actual database (constently load 1 and then swap when finished and load again). You could try breaking the staging/ETL into the smallest possible units. We use projects so we stage/load a project (several concurrently) but it's a form of # 1 with a very small staging refresh comparatively.

Comment: @Nick. Thanks for your comment. How could (2) be achieved? I did a lot of Google searches but did not find anything useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use method #1.

We log the execution start of the SSIS package that refreshes the staging database to a table, and log the completion or error to a separate column in the same row.

Our ETL processes check the most recent row in that table to determine whether the staging refresh is currently running, and how old the staging data is.

If the data is too stale, the ETL package can force a refresh by calling the other package, if necessary.